# Regression Analysis with String values in column of DataFrame

Tags: r, python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which is having multiple columns where some column has string values with comma seperated

```
row.names   MOVIE   Year    Released    Genre
1   2   Jilla   2014    10/01/14    Action, Drama, Thriller
2   3   Pursuit of Happyness    2005    16/07/05    Documentary
3   4   The Karate Kid  1984    22/06/84    Action, Drama, Family
4   5   Yes Man 2008    19/12/08    Comedy, Romance
5   6   The Butterfly Effect    2004    23/01/04    Sci-Fi, Thriller
6   7   Unknown 2011    18/02/11    Action, Mystery, Thriller
```

Now I have dataset which is having String value in a column but that is required for regression analysis.
Now I want to deal with this Genre Column which is extremely important for my analysis (regression).

So how can I deal with such column where I have string values.

I thought of finding all unique String values in the column and assign a number to each one of them.

```
Sci-Fi - 1
Thriller - 2
Comedy - 3

Now if any genre says -
Sci-Fi,Comedy  - 13
```

I will replace as above but I am not sure about this technique.

Is there any more proper mathematical approach I must follow

I am using both R and Pandas for doing the same.

Comment: What do you want to know? Is Sci-Fi a different genre from Sci-Fi,Comedy?

Comment: A movie can have more than 1 genre, so when I run linear regression I'd like to use Genre as input variable but since Genre is string type with more one values  so I want to deal with such situation, Yeah Sci-fi is different genre from Comedy